# How to get only a part from a string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list with the following strings:

```
total 71708
-rw-rw-rw- 1   gpatwprd        tmwdprd 221     Nov 19 12:36 20181116.Something name.6781773.CSV
-rw-rw-rw- 1   gpatwprd        tmwdprd 221     Nov 19 12:36 20171116.Something name.67885.CSV
```

And I would like to extract:

1. Only the filename which starts from 20181116 (or any other data, this is a dynamic number)
2. Only filenames with .CSV and .XLSX

Note that the filename can be variable in length.

How can I do this in python 3?

Comment: starts from or starts with? Any date after 20181116 should be extracted or not?

Comment: Just the entire filename if its a file with a .csv or .xlsx extension and the name starts indeed with 20181116

Comment: just loop over each element of the list, then split the string and check if the corresponding element starts with the desired string and the next element ends with CSV or XLSX

Comment: BTW, it's generally considered bad practice to parse the output of `ls`, since it varies so much, but it is safe if your script is only running on your own machine. But why not use standard Python library functions to get the file names? It's much more straightforward.

Comment: Yes it seems not optimal. Thus why I asked the following question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560846/list-filenames-on-ftp-without-the-meta-in-front

Answer (score -1):

The following code will print a list of all the required entries and also a list that has only **names** of required files. 'data.txt' is the file which has the data to be used. Hope this helps!

```
fileContent = open('data.txt','r');
readLinesfromContent = fileContent.readlines();

splitLinesforSpace = []
for line in readLinesfromContent:
    splitLinesforSpace.append(line.split())

requiredEntries = []
namesofRequiredFiles = []
for idx, x in enumerate(splitLinesforSpace):
    if len(x) == 10:
        if x[8].startswith('20181116'):
            if x[9].endswith('.CSV') or x[9].endswith('.XLSX'):
                requiredEntries.append(readLinesfromContent[idx])
                x[9] = x[9].split('.')
                #Following gives only names of files
                namesofRequiredFiles.append(x[9][0])

print(requiredEntries)
print(namesofRequiredFiles)
```