# List filenames on ftp without the meta in front

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of filenames in a ftp directory. I tried the following:

```
import ftplib
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

class FtpObj:
    def __init__(self, host, user, password):
        self.ftp = ftplib.FTP(host)
        self.ftp.login(user=user, passwd=password)

    def list_files(self):
        files = []
        self.ftp.dir(files.append)

        print('Found ' + str(len(files)) + 'Files')
        return files
```

However, this returns me a `list` of weirdly formatted file names in the format:

```
total 71708
-rw-rw-rw- 1   gpatwprd        tmwdprd 4799    Nov 30 05:43 20181129.Name A with Space.CSV
-rw-rw-rw- 1   gpatwprd        tmwdprd 290     Nov 30 05:09 20181129.name D with Space.CSV
```

The first part `-rw-rw-rw- 1   gpatwprd        tmwdprd 4799    Nov 30 05:43`  and the first line `total 71708` are all meta data and redundant.

How can I get just the raw filenames without all of this messy text?

---

This is not the same as [How to get only a part from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560606/how-to-get-only-a-part-from-a-string-in-python)
Why: because I am looking for a cleaner way to extract the filenames. In the other question its about having a list of strings and then parsing part of those string. Totally UNRELATED. Please READ my question before you flag it as a possible duplicate, I noticed this happening quite often.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get only a part from a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53560606/how-to-get-only-a-part-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: No its not a duplicate. I am explicitly asking how to get the filenames without the meta.

Comment: And you already have the answer in the other question.

Comment: No because in the other question its parsing strings in a list. Here I want to avoid to parse strings and get directly the filenames from a directory listing which should be cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this function of ftplib.FTP to get a list of filenames:

```
files = ftp.nlst()
```

From the [ftplib docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html#ftplib.FTP.nlst)